# invalid input by the user

Tags: c++

hey guys so this is my program, I need to notify the user that if hhe/she enters a letter other than w d b or w that is an invalid request. what ive done so far does this, but when i input a number to the dollars_withdraw or dollars_deposit or account_balance the program will do the transaction but also add the "invalid request" before going back to main loop. how do i change it so the program wont do that for numerical inputs for the withdraw deposit and balance?:

```
// Atm machine.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   char user_request;
   string user_string;
   double account_balance, dollars_withdraw, dollars_deposit;

   account_balance = 5000;


   while(account_balance >0)
     {
       cout << "Would you like to [W]ithdraw, [D]eposit, Check your [b]alance or [Q]uit?" 
           << endl;
       cin >> user_string;
       user_request= user_string[0];
       if(user_request == 'w' || user_request== 'W')
        {
           cout << "How much would you like to withdraw?" << endl;
           cin >> dollars_withdraw;
           if (dollars_withdraw > account_balance || dollars_withdraw <0)
            cout << "Invalid transaction" << endl;
           else 
            account_balance = account_balance - dollars_withdraw;
            cout << "Your new balance is $" << account_balance << endl;
       }
       if (user_request == 'd' || user_request== 'D')
        {
           cout << "How much would you like to deposit?" << endl;
           cin >> dollars_deposit;
           if (dollars_deposit <0)
              cout << "Invalid transaction" << endl;
           else 
              account_balance= account_balance + dollars_deposit;
              cout << "Your new balance is $" << account_balance << endl;
        }
       if(user_request == 'b' || user_request == 'B')
       {
           account_balance= account_balance;
           cout << "Your available balance is $" << account_balance << endl;
       }
      if(user_request == 'q' || user_request == 'Q')
           break;
      else
           cout << "Invalid request " << endl;

   }
        cout << "Goodbye" << endl;



  return 0;
}
```

Comment: my bad it just formatted that way i dont know why

Comment: the reason it formatted it that way is because you didn't indent your code. The way to let the markdown feature know something should be formatted as code is by indenting each line with at least 4 spaces. As a shortcut, you can also select the entire block of code and click the `{}` button in the toolbar. Just so you'll know for next time!

Answer (score 2):

Sure it does. Your code says:

- If it is a 'w' do something
- ...
- If it is a 'q' do something, **else yell "invalid"**

So if the user does not enter a 'q', the last 'else' block will always be executed.  Either use `else if` throughout or change your code to use a `switch` statement:

```
// Either:
if (user_request == ...) {
    ...
} else if (user_request == ...) {
    ...
} else {
    std::cout << "invalid";
}

// Or (better, faster):
switch (user_request) {
case 'q':
case 'Q':
    ...
    break;
...
default:
    std::cout << "Invalid request";
}
```

A third option would be to use `continue`:

```
while (...) {
    user_request = ...
    if (user_request == 'w' ...) {
        ...
        continue; // In this iteration, no other code within the while loop is executed.
    }
    if (...)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad programming practice. Please use Switch Case for what you need to achieve. And put a "break" statement after every case branch.

Comment: While true, it doesn't really answer his question.

Comment: +1.  @Maxpm, it does answer the question *indirectly* :)  If he was using `switch` then he wouldn't be having this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

chain your if statements into if, else-if, else-if, ..., else.

Answer (score 1):

`else` statements only "know of" the `if` statement immediately previous.  For example:

```
if (myNumber == 0)
{
    // Triggers when myNumber is zero.
}

if (myNumber == 1)
{
    // Triggers when myNumber is one.
}

else
{
    // Triggers when myNumber is not one.
}
```

This can be fixed with `else if` statements.  In your case it would look something like this:

```
if (user_request == w)
{
    // ...
}

else if (user_request == d)
{
    // ...
}

// ...

else cout << "Invalid request.";
```

Answer (score 0):

In my old CS class, I'd do things like this:

```
string user_string;
do {
    if(user_string) cout << "Enter a valid value!" << endl;
    cin >> user_string;
} while(user_string != "w" && user_string != "d");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `else if` as follows:

```
if(user_request == 'w' || user_request== 'W')
{
    ...
} else if(user_request == 'd' || user_request== 'D')
{
    ....
} else if(user_request == 'b' || user_request== 'B')
{
    .....
} else if(user_request == 'q' || user_request== 'Q')
{
    ...
} else
{
   // Invalid request
}
```